# How can I use LLVM's libcxx & libcxxabi in a CMake project?

Tags: cmake, llvm, clang++, include-path, libc++

Currently I'm running [Debian 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_9_(Stretch)) (Stretch) with the system's default compiler GCC 6.3.0. But I have a project using CMake ([ceph](https://github.com/ceph/ceph)'s master branch) that depends on [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17), which requires non default includes and libraries. So I decided to use [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) and [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) to build it. I downloaded and installed Clang and LLVM, compiled it, and installed it below `/usr/local`.

How can I instruct CMake to use the includes from `/usr/local/include/c++/v1/` and the libraries from `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: I guess, `-stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: @arrowd That main problem is, how to instruct cmake to use the non-default libs. The -stdlib switch is only a little puzzle piece of it and does not answer, how to pass it to cmake.

Comment: ([The profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3899944/themole?tab=profile): *"linux"* → *"[Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux)"* . *"econimcal"* → *"[economical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/economical#Adjective)"*. *"roman empire"* → *"[Roman Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Empire)"*)